# How to configure Kotlin SDK external documentation in Intellij?

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, documentation

According to the IntelliJ documentation:

> External documentation opens the necessary information in a web browser, so that you can navigate to related symbols and keep the information for further reference at the same time.

This works well with Java by selecting File -> Project structure... -> SDKs -> Documentation paths -> Specify URL and setting the URL `https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/`.

How to do the same in Kotlin ?

[image]

== Edit ==

This issue has already been reported to Jetbrains, but apparently closed without resolution : https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-234490

Comment: Can you describe your use case? Kotlin documentation is already shown in IDEA documentation popup, which I think is the main use case for such feature.

Comment: I don't like to read documentation in popups. I prefer to have a browser where I can open multiple tabs and see all methods of a class in a same window. I always use the external documentation feature in Java, why it's not possible in Kotlin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

External documentation feature is currently not implemented for the Kotlin IDEA plugin. As a workaround you can [view quick documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/viewing-reference-information.html#inline-quick-documentation) in a popup.

You can vote for the feature request at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-41690